# div popup display under table borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I build bootstrap table with chosen jquery popup inside and I set the table to be x-scrollable when the table viewed on max-width:512px media query to:

```css
@media (max-width:512px){
  table {
    overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

so the table keeps the width and just scroll horizontally.

The problem i'm facing, when the view with width more than the media queries limits the popup, which I built using chosen jquery plugin, it displays correctly but when the view gets smaller width the popup appears under the borders of the table, I tried all the positions and displays in css but no luck.

you can view the table: http://plnkr.co/edit/rQmrAwjQO0tg1SH2CIko?p=preview

To see the problem re-size the preview to smaller width until you see the horizontal scroller.

I want to make the popup display above the table.

Please Advice,

Comment: It's a pretty common problem: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/746

Comment: even if you remove the hidden overflow the problem still there! I wish someone would help me to solve this issue I almost destroyed my PC from hitting.......

Comment: can any one help me to solve this issue?¿?